# Efficient BigInteger in Java

Tags: java, biginteger

We have a set of locations within our product where BigInteger is required as the numbers can be fairly long. However, in over 90% of the cases, they are actually not that long and can be easily contained with-in a long.

Looking at BigInteger's implementation, it would be quite a waste to use BigInteger where Long is sufficient.

Would it make sense to create an Interface that has functions like BigInteger (divide, multiply, etc.) and that would be implemented by a child class of BigInteger and a class that wraps Long? Something like:

```
Interface: EfficientBigInteger
Class 1: MyBigInteger extends BigInteger imlpements EfficientBigInteger
Class 2: MyLong implements EfficientBigInteger (this will contain a Long, as we cannot extend the Long class)
```

Maybe we're in the wrong direction here?

Thanks,
Yon

**UPDATE:** These objects (Long or BigInteger) are stored in memory for quite a while as they help us identify problematic behaviors of systems we interact with. Therefore, the memory footprint could be a problem. This is the problem we're trying to avoid. The BigInteger class has several fields (signum, mag array, bitcount, etc. etc.) which together are roughly double that of a class that encapsulates Long (taking into account the memory costs of having an Object in the first place). It means double the footprint for something we use a lot of.

Comment: How are you going to detect overflow on operations involving Long?

Comment: Do you have a performance problem, and have you profiled the application to make sure it comes from the operations on small BigIntegers? If not, you're trying to optimize prematurely.

Comment: A BigInteger which's value fits in a `long` does not actually takes that much more space than a single `Long` value would do - it has an array of `long` (of size 1). Having separate classes and implementing arithmetic between them is just complicated, if it is not integrated in the VM (as some smalltalk VMs do).

Comment: @vineet-reynolds - we can add a lot of checks to the code, which would cost in CPU instead of memory (remember that memory costs CPU as well, though).

Comment: @jb-nizet We expect one as we've had many memory-related performance problems in the past which drove us to reduce memory usage as much as possible.

Comment: @paulo-ebermann There are several fields in BigInteger which together bring us to about twice the memory footprint of a class that encapsulates Long.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have to do arithmetic on these values? Because if you do, then one that starts out as a long may become a BigInteger, and that sounds like a pain: You'd have to precede every arithmetic operation with a test that it might go over MAX_LONG. Well, I suppose you could encasulate all this in your wrapper class. How much time would it take to test for overflow, compared to the time that the BigInteger class takes to loop through an array of 1 or 2 elements?

If you're not doing arithmetic, then the savings by using a long would be minimal. What are you doing with the BigInteger, just reading it in and writing it out? In that case almost surely not worth the trouble.

Personally, this is the sort of thing that I would be tempted to do myself, I understand your thinking. But then I would step back and say: Is performance really a problem here? JUst how much arithmetic are we doing? How much performance gain would we get? Is it worth adding to the complexity of the program and possibly introducing bugs?

Unless you have reason to believe that performance is really a problem and that doing this would make a significant difference, I wouldn't.

Comment: The introduction of bugs is possible but given this code will be limited to a couple of classes we can aggressively unit test it until we're certain it's working well. The CPU load of testing for overflows is not anticipated to be a big issue as we rarely do arithmetic on these values.

In terms of the performance gain, our calculation shows that BigInteger takes twice the amount of memory of a class that encapsulates Long. If this is true, and we store many BigIntegers, there could be quite a footprint here.

Comment: Sure if you work hard enough you can have a high confidence that the code is correct. My point is: Is it worth the effort? And: No matter how hard you work, there's always a non-zero possibility of a subtle bug making it to production. If it's for a function that adds value to the application, of course that's just how life is. But if it's for a whim, why add risk?

Comment: As to memory, by a quick look at the source I think a BigInteger would take 32 bytes plus object overhead to store a number that would fit in a long, so sure, it's more memory. But do you have millions of these in memory at one time? If you have a few hundred, you might "waste" several k. If you really have to hold millions of them or you're in some highly constrained environment, maybe it's worth it. If not, well, on a modern desktop a megabyte is nothing. Who cares? I'm very concerned about optimization myself, I hate to waste memory or CPU cycles. But you don't want to go crazy about it.

Comment: Further thought: If memory is the issue, how many of these numbers do you have in memory at one time? If it's a dozen, the memory taken by a new class definition could well be more than what a dozen BigInteger's take. If you have millions of them, maybe the problem is not that each number is too big, but that you are keeping too much in memory. I have no idea what your application is, but perhaps instead of "read everything, then process" you could "read, process; read, process; etc".

Comment: We use these numbers to analyze the behavior of certain elements in devices we work with. A calculation would be:
Each sub-element in a device has 30-40 of these integers.
Each device has up to 20 sub-elements.
The system is designed to handle up to 1000 devices.

So it's up to 800,000 of these integers. The overhead is of about 30MB, correct? If so, it's no major issue and you are very right.

Answer (score 5):

I implemented exactly such a thing for a Cobol compiler in about 1986. It made no difference to performance whatsoever: the overhead of deciding whether it would fit in a long and then converting it to a long and then back again equalled the time saving.